# Stackplot with strings

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd

sectors = [['Industrials', 'Health Care', 'Information Technology', 'Industrials'], ['Health Care', 'Health Care', 'Information Technology'], ['Industrials', 'Information Technology', 'Health Care', 'Information Technology', 'Information Technology'], ['Information Technology', 'Health Care']]
some_date = ['2015-12-01', '2016-01-05', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01']
somelist = []
for i in range(len(some_date)):
    somelist.append((some_date[i], sectors[i]))
df = pd.DataFrame(somelist, columns = ['date', 'sectors'])
```

I would like to create a [plt.stackplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot.html) where the X-axis is the date and the Y-axis is number of times any sector is mentioned.

The problem is that it's strings and not integers, one approach could be to iterate through each row of the `DataFrame` and count how many times each sector is mentioned for each date, but I don't always know the names of the sectors I have so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to solve this?

I tried to plot a [plt.pie](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) by using `df['sectors'].sum()` to check how many times throughout the complete date-range each sector is mentioned, but for this I would also somehow need to convert the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this is, but I fixed the data as shown here;

```
plot_sectors = list(set(df['sectors'].sum()))
plot_sectors = {key: [0]*df.shape[0] for key in plot_sectors}
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for sector in df.iloc[i]['sectors']:
        plot_sectors[sector][i] += 1
```

For the stacked plot, I used;

```
y = plot_sectors.values()
x = np.arange(df.shape[0])
plt.stackplot(x,y, labels = plot_sectors.keys())
```

And for the pie plot I used;

```
plt.pie([sum(values) for key, values in plot_sectors.items()], autopct='%1.1f%%',
        labels=plot_sectors.keys())
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```